# Deploy API Platform 2.6 and Symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I created a project with Api platform 2.6 & Symfony 5.4 and then I uploaded it with FileZilla (FTP).

I followed the step to deploy a Symfonyproject update composer packages and change database in .env.
I sent the project online so that it would be avalaible on a domain name like my-website.com.
The symfony part works well but when I try to reach "my-website.com/api" I get code 404 even if I a set env=prod I get the 404 page.

Is there any action to activate/start api platfrom after deploying online ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you reach another route with a simple controller ? Like my-website.com/test

Comment: I modified /config/routes.yaml and put this =>
index: 
    path: /test
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

But I get a 404 again.
I have a route for api_platform also.

Comment: Are you calls getting to your front controller and the router ? Your web server (Apache, Nginx, Caddy...) might need configuration to redirect to the `public/` directory.

Comment: I set my domain to reach directly /public directory and I can see the first page of symfony "Your application is now ready and you can start working on it." the one you get when you start a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everybody !

I found the solution.
I was missing a htaccess file in the /public directory.
I found one here : https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/main/symfony/apache-pack/1.0/public/.htaccess

And from now routes work fine !
I just have to take a look at the htaccess to check the content

Answer (score 2):

You should try composer `composer require symfony/apache-pack` if your web server is running Apache.

See also : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html